# How to do XHR in Azure Function App

Tags: javascript, azure, xmlhttprequest, serverless

I want to fire an http API and process it's response but I am getting following error:

Exception while executing function: Functions.getAccessObject. mscorlib: ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined

Here's my Azure serverless function Code:

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {

function getAccessObject(context, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    var APPLICATION_ID = "zzz";
    var APPLICATION_SECRET = "zzz";
    var REFRESH_TOKEN = "zzz";

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    xhr.open("GET", "https://xyz");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("applicationid", APPLICATION_ID);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("applicationsecret", APPLICATION_SECRET);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("refreshtoken", REFRESH_TOKEN);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                successCallback(context, request.responseText);
            } else {
                failureCallback(context, request.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    request.send(null);

}
getAccessObject(context, registerForWebhookFunc, failureCallbackFunc);
}
```

Comment: Man, thanks for asking this.  Got suck on this writing a vanilla javascript function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe XHR is a browser API and not native to node.js. You can use the built-in http functionality of node.js (see example below) or alternatively other popular packages are available such as Axios that can do http requests. I believe there may even be one for XHR if you are set on using that.

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('http://myapi', (resp) => {
   let data = '';

   resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
     data += chunk;
   });

   resp.on('end', () => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });

   }).on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err.message);
   });
 }
```